# How can I implement a custom iNode on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

So every directory, file, queue or whatever in Linux creates it's own inodes that can be accessed in one way or another. How would I go about implementing my own inode type that doesn't quite fit any of the existing descriptions? A custom something that is visible in the file system but isn't a file? Do I have to extend the kernel or is there some simpler approach?

Comment: You have to stick with one of the known types.  file, two kinds of devices, two or three kinds of pipes, symlinks, and directories.  /proc does some magic, but most of the results are files or directories or symlinks.

Comment: I mean... if i extend the kernel, i can do anything. But is it partition-specific or is it somewhere in the kernel? I'm not sure where to look for this

Comment: "A custom something that is visible in the file system but isn't a file?" - Do you actually want to add new **type** of a file object, aside from existing regular file, directory, symlink an so? How that new type should affect on the rest of OS? If you expect user-space utilities (like `ls`) to print that type, then you need to modify that utilities. If you want to add a new command to work with that new file, then you could implement this command as a syscall, or as a new ioctl request. Your problem description is quite vague for give more specific solution(s).

Comment: is that so? ls relies on the inode to be there. As long as it has all the necessary attributes, what difference will it make?

Comment: The `inode` has to get "there" somehow. If "there" is the filesystem, then only the kernel can attach inodes directly. You can do this via syscall (ie, `creat` or `open` or `mknod`), or inside a kernel filesystem module. The exception is [FUSE](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html), where a generic kernel module can delegate implementation to a userspace process.

Comment: nice! that's a start i guess. thank you!

Comment: In short, it is very unlikely you need a new base file type, and can just use one of the existing ones to do what you want.  Before you try to create something new, you should make sure you understand what is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So every directory, file, queue or whatever in Linux creates it's own inodes that can be accessed in one way or another.

***False***.  Directories, files *etc*. do not create their own inodes.  They are stored with use of inodes belonging to the filesystem on which they are stored.  The inodes are not even created specifically for particular files -- all inodes are created as part of filesystem creation, before there are any files stored on it.<sup>*</sup>

> How would I go about implementing my own inode type that doesn't quite fit any of the existing descriptions?

It's unclear why you think you need a custom inode type, but if you do, then you need a whole custom filesystem.  You will need to write either kernel drivers or FUSE drivers implementing it, plus all the needed utilities for formatting a device with that FS, mounting and unmounting it, checking it for errors, *etc*.

> A custom something that is visible in the file system but isn't a file? Do I have to extend the kernel or is there some simpler approach?

*Everything* is a file.  This is one of the principles of UNIX.  But perhaps you mean something that isn't a *regular* file.  Unfortunately for you, even a custom file system and inode wouldn't be enough to give you a custom file type.  The partition of filesystem entries regular files, directories, character and block special files, *etc*. is deeply ingrained in the kernel and the standard file management APIs and utilities.  You would not only have to extend the kernel (beyond writing filesystem drivers), but also modify the C standard library, several standard utilities, and probably a bunch of other libraries and utilities affected by those changes.  In the end, you basically have your own whole operating system.

But maybe your premise is wrong.  UNIX has been going along just fine with pretty much its current file model for a very long time.  It's unclear why you want what you say you want, but there are at least two simpler options that might suit you:

- Write a kernel driver for a character or block device with a filesystem interface, and use the system's existing facilities to link one or more device instances to the filesystem as a character or block special file.
- Embed what you want to do in regular files / directories / *etc*.

---

<sup>*</sup>More or less. I ignore special administrative actions that may in some cases be able to expand a filesystem and add inodes to it in the process.

Comment: wow. That's a long one. Sure. I suppose my understanding of the topic is wrong. So... objects like `/dev/null` or `/proc/$$/fd` that are not really files, but are visible in the file system. Are these really specific to ext2/3/4 ? I don't want to go into details, because perhaps my use case is silly. I'm just looking into my options for a side project :P

Comment: @KamilJanowski, `/dev/null` is an example of a character special device file.  This is not specific to ext2/3/4, though not *all* filesystems support character and block device files.  What is conventionally mounted at `/proc`, that provides files such as you describe, is a special filesystem built into the kernel.  It has nothing at all to do with ext2/3/4.  And I don't think it even uses inodes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Linux kernel creates inodes for files under `/proc` too. These inodes are created by procfs filesystem when requested (e.g. when one reads the file `/proc/$$/fd` or iterates over files in `/proc` directory).

Comment: There's a fine distinction between "created" inodes that reside on a disk and "virtual" inodes that are manifestations of code with no physical existence.   But in either case, the inodes exist even if only virtually.